# Install magento 2.0 successfully but backend getting error

Tags: magento

I am using XAMPP server, When i setup magento 2.0 on my localhost it is successfully installed but when i login on backend. i can't click on anything. there are many bugs on console relate to js

[image]

Anyone can help me. thanks a lots!

Comment: Run magento setup:static-content:deploy command for your magento folder

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove pub/static
2. Remove var/cache
3. Remove var/composer_home
4. Remove var/generation
5. Remove var/page_cache
6. Remove var/view_preprocessed
7. run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
8. Logout and login admin area

Comment: its good i like this. thanks again!